# SQL query : employee relationships

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called "employment" which looks like

[image]

if the boss column is empty it means he/she is the "CEO"

and if he/she manages one another under boss column it means "Manager"

else it's "Worker"

Finally it should look like

[image]

Can you help build some query to make the following result?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT name,
       CASE WHEN boss = ''   -- or maybe WHEN boss IS NULL 
            THEN 'CEO'
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM employment t2 WHERE t1.name = t2.boss)
            THEN 'MANAGER'
            ELSE 'WORKER'
            END posession
FROM employment t1
```

Answer (score 0):

So, this can be solved using the case expression.

```
select Name,
case 
    when BOSS = "" then "CEO"
    when exists(select NULL from employment t2 where t1.NAME = t2.BOSS) then "MANAGER"
    else "WORKER"
end as BOSS
from Employment t1
```